# Why does setSpan() stop affecting the SpannableStringBuilder when the device is rotated?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, spannablestring

I ran into a painful bug recently, and finally managed to procure a minimal repro. Here it is:

```
private EditText mEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // This check ensures the code below is not run when onCreate() is called
    // due to a change in screen orientation.
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811999/4077294
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // In the layout: main_editText has is an EditText with its text set to "Hello world!"
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_editText);
        workLoop(0);
    }
}

private void workLoop(final int index) {
    Editable text = mEditText.getText();
    if (index == text.length()) {
        return;
    }

    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            workLoop(index + 1);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

When you run this code and keep the device in portrait mode, it will color each character of `Hello world!` blue in 5 second intervals.

When you run this code and change it to landscape mode, it will abruptly stop coloring characters blue. I determined via the debugger that `setSpan()` is still being called, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the color. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to call `text.clearSpans()` to release the spannable string.

Comment: What if I want to keep the `ForegroundColorSpans` that are already there, though?

Comment: Are you handling the configuration changes for the layout?